# Doctrine XOR two relationships on an entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Given an entity `A`, which is connected with entities `B` and `C` through the *optional* ManyToOne relationships - what would be the best way to make sure that only one of those relationships is used at a time (XOR)?

What I'm trying to achieve is pretty well illustrated by the following image (cardinality is shown differently there):

[image]

Of course, I can make sure that references are valid under a Repository code or elsewhere, but maybe there is a more "proper" way to do that by using Doctrine mapping features?

A

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="A")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\AppBundle\Repository\ARepository")
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="as", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $b = null;

    /**
     * @var null
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="C", inversedBy="as", cascade={"all"}))
     */
    private $c = null;
}
```

B

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="B")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\AppBundle\Repository\BRepository")
 */
class B
{
    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="b", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $as = null;
}
```

C

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="C")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\AppBundle\Repository\CRepository")
 */
class C
{
    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="c", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $as = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a build-in solution for this (and there is no best practice for doctrine either), but here are some thoughts that might help you:

**1. Using getter/setter methods to "null" the $b association if $c gets set and vice-versa**

Would look like this:

```
public function setB($b) {
    $this->b = $b;
    if($b !== null) {
        $this->c = null;
    }
}
```

Advantage is that it will not be possible for your entity to have an invalid state where both $b and $c are set. However, doctrine is using reflection e.g. if entity instances are created from persistent objects to prevent the __construct call. It *might* be that there is also a reason for setter methods so your entity gets into an unwanted state, but I cannot substatiate my allegation (maybe to prevent some kind of dirty state).

Also, you could consider this as a side effect that may be unwanted for users of your `A` class (especially in a simple setter method you would not expect this behaviour). This is something you have to elaborate in your context.

This solution is okay with symfony forms. As long as the properties are not public, the forms system [will call the setter methods](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-the-form):

> Unless a property is public, it must have a "getter" and "setter" method so that the Form component can get and put data onto the property.

**2. Using lifecycle callbacks**

I would go for this method personally as I think it is easier to understand. (see [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html))

Example using prePersist:

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
* @ORM\PreUpdate
*/
public function checkAssociations()
{
    if($this->a !== null && $this->b !== null) {
        // throw some error
    }
}
```

This code is

- Better readable (imo) because it is more "plaintext-like" (*"If both a and b are set, throw an error"*) than the setter-solution
- Less error prone (no guarantee that your setter methods get called)

Hope that helps.

If someone has more info on the setter calls in symfony that would be great.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll betetr go with the lifecycle callbacks since the setters based approach is much more error prone indeed (like setting one thing, then the other - and wondering why it ends up with the wrong one set)